# Issue with firebase phone auth, not sending verification SMS

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app uses firebase phone auth to allow users to register, the issue is that I don't receive any verification code. but when I use a VPN app and try, it works!!

am sure that there is no issue in the code, since it works when I use a VPN. am wondering is it cause of my current location (I am based in Sudan)? although Sudan is listed in among the countries where the service is offered too in the documentation.

I think it could be that google services doesn't work here? but play store, other features etc. work like a charm. I know Sudan is under US sanction, so are other countries - does that mean this feature wont work at all?

If anyone knows whats going on let me know please!
Thank you

Comment: Sudan should be supported (not sure about South Sudan) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44274724/7132300

Comment: yeah weird part is I checked the docs and sudan is listed. I am in North Sudan sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of the library (4.2.0). However, it could be a service issue, as the library does rely on APNs in many cases for validation.

Comment: Hi Abdeen, Did you get any solution?

Comment: hey vidha, nope not really to this problem but to solve my case I just didn't removed the part where verification is necessary

Comment: Salam @AbdeenM., I hope you got a solution.?

Comment: Salam, sadly no. But if you are looking for a paid service check out sinch.

Comment: @AbdeenM. Hi, were you able to use other Firebase features (ie. Firebase Firestore / Email Auth) from Sudan? I've developed an app specifically targeting users of Sudan while I was in KSA (not knowing it wouldn't work for my users) until I finished writing everything unfortunately! I found out when I sent it to a friend to test it. Phone authentication and Firestore (Realtime Databases) aren't working.

Comment: @AlaaElrifaie Hi! apologise for the delay with the reply.
Sadly there is no work around unless the user uses vpn then it MIGHT work sometimes, i ended up using sinch which is good but cost can go up pretty quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way around it, due to the sanctions exposed in Sudan firebase or in fact all google services will not work unless you use a VPN.

For anyone else who runs into something like this, i did use a work around using [this](https://www.sinch.com/) service.

Hope this helps!